# How to create filebeat index pattern in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm currently using ELK stack with filebeat. I'm able to map the apache log file contents to Elasticsearch server in json format. Now I would like to know how to create a index pattern for filebeat in kibana? Followed below link but that did not help.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-index-pattern.html

Answer (score 2):

As stated on the page you linked, "To load this pattern, you can use the script that’s provided for importing dashboards." So before you will see the `filebeat-*` index pattern you should run the `./scripts/import_dashboards` tool then refresh the page. This will write the index pattern into the `.kibana` index used by Kibana.

For Linux when installed by rpm or deb the command is:

```
/usr/share/filebeat/scripts/import_dashboards -es http://elasticsearch:9200
```

If you are using the tar or zip package the command is located in the `scripts` directory of the package.

You can further manage or modify index patterns in Kibana by going to `Management` -> `Index Patterns`.