# How does one create an Index Pattern in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-6, kibana-6

I've installed Kibana 6.2.1 on my box and it says that I need to create an `Index Pattern` before I can use it.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to actually create one.  All the guides I've seen suggest going into Settings and creating one there.  However, those guides are for earlier versions of the product because the screenshots don't match up.  Here is what I am seeing:

[image]

So what am I missing?  Is there a button I am not seeing?

P.S. I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711986/how-to-create-index-pattern-for-kibana) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582943/how-to-create-filebeat-index-pattern-in-kibana) one, but it's for earlier versions.

Comment: You might want to click `Learn how`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1) go to dev tools in the left side bar and there create index for example:

```
Post my-index/doc
   {
       Name:"blah"

    }
```

Now go to management and create the index pattern my-index.

2) download the elastic makelogs repository:

```
Npm install -g makelogs
```

Then type :

```
makelogs
```

The go to management and create the logstash-* index pattern.